# python pandas to_datetime change format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My input is text based, e.g. Column "ClosedDate" = "2016-10-31 16:54:18"

With:

```
df.ClosedDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ClosedDate).dt.date
```

I format that as "2016-10-31", i.e. keeping the date part only and dropping the time, which works fine so far, but what I need is "31.10.2016".

what would be the best and most "elegant way to accomplish that? 
I tried adding a "format = "%d%m%Y" but that doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: you'd need to use `strftime` to do this: `df.ClosedDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ClosedDate).dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')` but this will give you a string not a datetime.date object

Comment: @EdChum tried that but it raises: TypeError: cannot convert an object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index and AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Sorry misplaced bracket, you need to call dt.strftime on the result of to_datetime

Comment: ah, so I can omit the .dt.date when specifying dt.strftime. Thanks

Comment: Well the column loses some usefulness when you convert it from a datetime to string as you won't be able to do arithmetic operations